# Duplicate sections in QML ListView

Tags: qt, qml

I am writing an application which inserts ListElements into a ListModel in C++ code, with each inserted ListElement containing a 'category' attribute. I want to be able to display unique sections, but the QML engine is displaying duplicate sections in the ListView.

The QML code containing the ListModel is contains the following:

```
ApplicationWindow {
//...
ListModel { id: theModel }
ListView { id: theList
    model: theModel

    section.property: "category"
    section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString
    section.delegate: ItemDelegate {
        Rectangle {
            Label {
                text: section
            }
        }
    }
}
//...
}
```

And the C++ code used to insert items into 'theModel' contains this:

```
QVariantMap temp;
QList<QVariant> listItems;
std::string itemName, itemCategory;
currentNode = rootNode->first_node("item");
while (currentNode) {
    itemName = currentNode->first_attribute("name")->value();
    itemCategory = currentNode->first_attribute("category")->value();
    temp.insert("itemName", QVariant::fromValue(QString(itemName.c_str())));
    temp.insert("price", QVariant::fromValue(qreal(0)));
    temp.insert("category", QVariant::fromValue(QString(itemCategory == "Fruit" ? "Default" : "Other")));
    listItems.append(temp);
    currentNode = currentNode->next_sibling("item");
}
listItems.append(temp);
//Append each list element
for (auto item : listItems) {
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(
        rootObject,
        "appendListItem",
        Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(item))
    );
}
```

Is there a way to prevent duplicate sections appearing in the ListView?

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: QML ListModel and Repeater worth exploring. And you can pass an entire list of QObject from C++ and read it in QML.

Comment: Does it have duplicate sections because the `ListModel` isn't sorted?

Comment: You could pass your listmodel through a `QSortFilterProxyModel`, sorting it for the category. You can do that in C++ or you expose one of them to QML and instantiate it there. AFAIK *@GrecKo* has a nice implementation for usage in QML in his github.

Comment: it's been 2 years, did you found an answer to this question ?